# Candle Stick Chart in Flutter flow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I was hoping someone had any ideas on how to create an candle stick chart in flutterflow. I understand this is going to require a custom widget, but I can find no information on how to get it done.

Im currently using an API call to get the Kline Information and Time, open, high, low, close are availabe in the json response as named json paths.

"https://legacy-community.flutterflow.io/c/community-tutorials/creating-a-custom-widget-chart-in-flutterflow-io-that-shows-data-from-a-list-of-documents"

Hoping to get a working candlestick chart out of this

Answer (score 0):

Use webview wiget it will help u you can add website that shows chart

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).